# want to know about webapplication urls

Tags: asp.net

Im running a web application in visual studio 2008...
while running, my first web page url is *http://localhost/ABC/default.aspx*
while i run this in another system, it is *http://localhost:2435/ABC/default.aspx*
Really eager to know what is this all about...
because the images in root folder are displaying in my system but not in another system...
Give me some idea about this..
Thank u in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, when running an ASP.NET site locally, if the URL host name is simply `localhost` on the default port, the site is hosted in IIS. If the URL host name includes a random high-order port, then the site probably runs on the Visual Studio development server.

You can configure how the development site is hosted on the `Web` tab of your project settings, if using a Web Application Project. If using a Web Site, hosting the site in IIS requires that you configure the site's virtual folder in IIS manually, and re-add the web site to your solution *from* IIS, instead of from the file system.

To resolve issues with your image references breaking, there are a few things you can check:

- When using server controls for images, favor prefixing your `ImageUrl` attributes with a tilde-slash (`~/`), which the server will resolve relative to the web application folder.
- When referencing images *outside* of your web application (e.g. some other parent, such as a sibling or a parent, ensure you have configured your site on IIS and that the dependencies are also installed on IIS in the correct location relative to your development site.
- Finally, if these actions do not resolve the issue, consider monitoring your network traffic with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com). This tool will enable you to see what images the browser *actually* requests, and diagnose where the assumptions went wrong. (Note that Fiddler won't listen on localhost. I have to use my machine's DNS name or IP address to capture requests from Fiddler on my local machine.)

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is that on one machine, the project is configured to use IIS as the application host for debugging, and that on the other, it is set to user the built-in web host for debugging (called cassini).  Either way, first stop should be the project settings...